# FAQ section in the sidebar has gone with the new navigation, if the layout is expanded

Tags: discussion, new-nav, homepage

There is such a section on metas (filled by employees with the questions they find faq-ish) before the new nav was rolled out; it was appearing on the [main page](/#) of any metas.

> [image]

Now, with the new nav being enabled on MSE and SO, I don't see this section on MSE or MSO if I choose the expanded layout. But this pref is sticky, so as I've chosen the expanded layout, any pages would show in expanded layout, including the homepage, which leaves me much less chances to see this sidebar, until I choose the compact one. Moreover, the homepage is still the homepage.

Therefore, I can't see a reason to remove that sidebar if I use the expanded layout.

Comment: On the wall in the Stack dev office is a piece of paper, other than "todo" written on the top it's virtually blank. On the other side of the office is a wall-sized piece of paper, full of hundreds of tasks. At the top it reads "todo (nicael)"...

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi9Fc.png

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I figured that. You're sorting by compact layout, maybe it's the problem.

Comment: @nicael ahh - yes that seems to be the problem! It kind of makes sense, because the non-compact layout is basically the page that *used* to be linked to 'Questions' at the top - and that *wasn't* the homepage. *However*, the new layout causes the non-compact layout to be the homepage *as well*, therefore it should be added!